# Mysql FK: Who should be the parent and who should be the children in the above situation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

For tables:

```
address: address_id, country, city
user: user_id, username, address_id
store: store_id, address_id, store_name
company: company_id, address_id, company_name
```

The relation i am interested here is around address_id

Between user and address tables (using address_id field) who is the parent and who is the children? I am thinking the Address is the parent since its used in multiple tables.

I mean address is the parent and user, store and company are the children.

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: From what I can tell, the address is definately the "parent" in this case.  All other entities simply link to an address.  However, can multiple objects link to the same address, and how do you handle deleting addresses which are no longer referenced by anything?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. NO, the objects will NOT link to same address. Address will be deleted only when a User/Store/Company will be deleted. Simply the address list is not managed, the address is updated/created when user is updated/created. Same for Store and Company.

Comment: in that case answer as below (which essentially confirms what you suspected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address.address_id` should be the primary key with `user.address_id store.address_id and company.address_id` being the foreign keys.  As you'll know however, you won't be able to take advantage of cascade on delete rules and will need to manage this yourself when another foreign record is removed.

Comment: Thank you, is there any method so we can use the cascade features? For example if we remove the user to remove the row from address?

Comment: @keepwalking Have the following columns on your address table (user_id, store_id, company_id). Set them all to Nullable, and set relationships between each table's id and the relevant new column in the address table.  Set  the relationship to cascade on delete and its a simple as that.

Comment: @keepwalking, I should also note then that you can remove the address_id column from user, store and company tables.